# Missing background image

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am having trouble getting my background image to show up

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Visit Jamaica</title>
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
   html {
    background: url(img/jamaica_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

The image is saved on an external harddrive 
fdrive/uni/assignment_2/img/jamaica_background.jpg

Comment: Try putting the background on the body instead

Comment: Do you mean just change the html selector on my stylesheet to body?

Comment: Is image present in the location `img/jamaica_background.jpg` ? If you are not sure of relative path try absolute path like `http://www.example.com/img/jamaica_background.jpg`

Comment: yes the image is in that location, it is stored on a seperate hd

Comment: Are you able to access the image by putting its http URL in the browser? If image path is correct and still you aren't able to access it on the browser, then there might not be enough permissions to read the image.

Comment: Diagnostic question: With the page open, press F12 for developer tools, click the Network tab, and then Refresh the page. Do you see a request for your image in the network request list?

Comment: What is the path to your HTML file?

Comment: well my site.css is in a folder for css and the image in question is in a separate folder for my images

Comment: Add the folder for the `site.css` file to your call of it. `<link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` becomes `<link href="{RELATIVE PATH FROM HTML FILE}/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Add `../` in front of your path. `background: url(../img/jamaica_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;`

Comment: I'd linked up my stylesheet incorrectly, should of been css/site.css instead of site.css

Comment: @TimWilliams Glad you got it fixed. I didn't spot your comment until after I posted my answer. Sorry about that. ^^'

Answer (score 1):

The pathing in HTML is relative to the file where content is being processed. From the comments, it sounds like your CSS is in a sub-directory, also, so I'm proceeding under that assumption. Take this file structure for example:

```
/
├index.html
├css
│└site.css
└img
 └jamaica_background.jpg
```

The `index.html` is your HTML file that calls the `css/site.css` file. This makes anything called from the `site.css` file relative to the `site.css`. Therefore, the call to `img/jamaica_background.jpg` is actually looking for `css/img/jamaica_background.jpg`.

Use the `../` to navigate up a directory from your `css` directory in your call to the `img/jamaica_background.jpg`.

Therefore, your `index.html` file should look something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Visit Jamaica</title>
        <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The `site.css` file should look like:

```
html {
    background: url(../img/jamaica_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 body {
 background: url(http://www.theluxurysignature.com/wp-    content/uploads/
 2015/01
 villa-6-ayara-kamala-phuket-img.jpg)
 no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 }
```

This works, I have picked a random img there, this means, you pic path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
background: url("../img/jamaica_background.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

I conducted a test by creating the same structure of the code presented here, Prem rather than using the given path (fdrive/uni/assignment_2/img/jamaica_background.jpg), created a folder called "img" in the same location where your HTML, and added the image (jamaica_background.jpg) that folder and it seemed to work just fine. See the structure of your folders.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but I fixed it using the `!important`.
Try this :

```
background: url(img/jamaica_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed !important;
```